Issues with CORS when sending API calls on local network
I'm trying to create an application that will take a midi signal from the host computer, read the midi data and when certain midi notes are detected, an API call is made to a piece of software running on another computer on the same network.  In my application, the user enters the IP Address and port of the second computer (located in the software's settings). The user also enters the name of the midi device they want to use.  This part is working fine.
Once WebMIDI.js detects a certain midi note, it uses the velocity of that note to send a particular API call.
The issue I'm running into is a CORS issue. I'll attach the code below as well as a copy of the error I'm receiving. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have not experienced CORS issues in the past and don't know very much at all about fetch().
The project is a Vite / Vue 3 project and it's been uploaded to Vercel.
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-8 p-4">
    <div>
      <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl font-black">
        ProPresenter 7 API control via MIDI (PP7APICVMIDI for short) v2.2
      </div>
      <div class="flex text-sm italic font-light">I'll think of a better name later...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-96">
      <div class="text-sm font-semibold">Please enter the IP address and port of the computer running ProPresenter 7</div>
      <div class="flex gap-4">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <label for="address">Address</label>
          <input class="px-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg w-36" v-model="address" type="text" :placeholder="address">
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <label for="port">Port</label>
          <input class="px-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg w-14" v-model="port" type="text" :placeholder="port">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <label for="device">MIDI Device</label>
        <input class="px-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg w-96" v-model="device" type="text" :placeholder="device">
      </div>
    <div class="p-4 my-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg w-96">
      <div>
        Playlist: {{ playlistName }}
      </div>
      <div>
        Song: {{ songName }}
      </div>
      <div>
        Slide: {{ slide }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
import {WebMidi} from 'webmidi';

const playlist = ref("0")
const song = ref("0")
const slide = ref("0")
const songName = ref("")
const playlistName = ref("")

const device = ref("IAC Driver Virtual Midi Port") //This parameter will be changed by the user.
const address = ref("192.168.0.1") //This parameter will be changed by the user.
const port = ref("1025") //This parameter will be changed by the user.

WebMidi
  .enable()
  .then(onEnabled)
  .catch(err => alert(err));

function onEnabled() {
  console.log("WebMidi enabled!");
  const myInput = WebMidi.getInputByName(device.value)
  myInput.addListener("noteon", e => {
    if (e.note.identifier === "F0") {
      playlist.value = e.rawVelocity - 1;
    } else if (e.note.identifier === "F#0") {
      song.value = e.rawVelocity - 1;
      const songURL = `https://${address.value}:${port.value}/v1/playlist/${playlist.value}/${song.value}/trigger`;
      fetch(songURL);
      fetchPlaylistName();
      fetchSongName();
    } else if (e.note.identifier === "G0") {
      slide.value = e.rawVelocity - 1;
      const slideURL = `https://${address.value}:${port.value}/v1/presentation/active/${slide.value}/trigger`;
      fetch(slideURL);
      fetchPlaylistName();
      fetchSongName();
    }
  })
}

const fetchSongName = async () => {
  try {
    const url = `https://${address.value}:${port.value}/v1/presentation/active`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    songName.value = data.presentation.id.name;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
  }
};

const fetchPlaylistName = async () => {
  try {
    const url = `${address.value}:${port.value}/v1/playlist/active`;
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json();
    playlistName.value = data.presentation.playlist.name;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
  }
}
</script>

The error I'm receiving:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://172.20.2.78:1025/v1/presentation/active/2/trigger. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

The little bit of reading I was able to find on Vercel's documentation said I could use a vercel.json file to enable cors and this would solve the issue, but it doesn't seem to work.
{
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

I'm at a loss at this point as I'm out of my depth.  I'm a musician who knows a little bit of javascript.. :P
